# Problems with displaying data in the view (angularjs)

Tags: html, angularjs, arrays, json

This is a json sample with 2 objects im retrieving:

```
 [{"project_id":"538","proyecto":"Caja","tarea":"DEF","fecha_termino":"00-00-00","estado":"Vencido","nombre_completo":"Christiano Ronaldo","alerta":"-Analista responsable: Lionel Messi.; \r\n-Estado Actual: DEF en Construcci\u00f3n detenido por el arbitro.; \r\n-Evaluaci\u00f3n validar en caja lejos. Validacion de pin de trajetas cau.;\r\n28-06-2017 : Usuario Suspende proyecto por cambio de prioridad."},{"project_id":"538","proyecto":"Caja ","tarea":"CAT y Capacity","fecha_termino":"00-00-00","estado":"Vencido","nombre_completo":"Christiano Ronalddo","alerta":"-Analista responsable: Lionel Messi.; \r\n-Estado Actual: DEF en Construcci\u00f3n detenido por capacity de Depto de Tarjetas.; \r\n-Evaluaci\u00f3n validar en caja atalla o redbanc. Validacion de pin de trajetas cau.;\r\n28-06-2017 : Usuario Suspende proyecto por cambio de prioridad."}]
```

I storage the data in angular to be displayed:

```
scope.llamada1 = function() { 

    $http.get("conector.php?tipoDato=query1")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.mensajeEspera = "";
        $scope.datos1 = response.data;

        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.datos1.length; i++){
            var currentObj = $scope.datos1[i];
            currentObj.TareasObj = currentObj.tarea + ", " + currentObj.fecha_termino + ", " + currentObj.estado + ", " + currentObj.nombre_completo;
            console.log(currentObj.TareasObj);
            $scope.detalleProyecto = currentObj.TareasObj;
            currentObj.detalleProyecto = currentObj.TareasObj;
        }
    $scope.detalleProyecto = currentObj.TareasObj;
    });
}
```

I have Projects, and each project can have multiple tasks, I need to display the data like this:

```
<table id="tablaTareas" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <td><b>Proyecto</b></td>
        <td><b>Alerta</b></td>
        <td><b>Tareas</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in datos1 ">
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{x.proyecto}}</td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{x.alerta}}</td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Tarea</b></td>
                        <td><b>Termino</b></td>
                        <td><b>Estado</b></td>
                        <td><b>Responsable</b></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="y in x.detalleProyecto track by $index">
                        <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{y.tarea}}</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{y.fecha_termino}}</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{y.estado}}</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{y.nombre_completo}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I dont know what is the problem with the code, i think i may be retrieving the data in angulajs in the wrong way?

Comment: *I dont know what is the problem with the code*: If you can't tell what the problem is, how could we help fixing it? Tell what you expect your code to do, and tell what it does instead. The code in the then() callback function doesn't make much sense. You should rethink about it.

Comment: Try to debug your code. May be put `console.log (response.data)` inside http.get.then () to see if there is data. if there is, then see if the datos1 has the value. and slowly you will reach a point where you will find the glitch.

Comment: @frager0 check the plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/AmVEq3gJrSRxTZux0lWa?p=preview

Comment: @sachilaranawaka the plnker is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.datos1.length; i++){
    var currentObj = $scope.datos1[i];
    $scope.datos1[i].detalleProyecto = [{
        "tarea":currentObj.tarea , 
        "fecha_termino":currentObj.fecha_termino , 
        "estado":currentObj.estado, 
        "nombre_completo":currentObj.nombre_completo
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like detalleProyecto of each datos1 needs tarea, fecha_termino, estado and nombre_completo which are missing.
And I dont understand why you need "$scope.detalleProyecto"., so i m omitting that out.

the for should atleast be this for it to work!

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.datos1.length; i++){
    var currentObj = $scope.datos1[i];
    currentObj.TareasObj = {tarea : currentObj.tarea ,  fecha_termino: currentObj.fecha_termino, estado:currentObj.estado, nombre_completo: currentObj.nombre_completo};
    currentObj.detalleProyecto = currentObj.TareasObj;
}
```

Comment: I think you will have to push currentObj.TareasObj into currentObj.detalleProyecto aarray. currentObj.detalleProyecto.push(currentObj.TareasObj);

Comment: thanks! im able to storage the data of the values i mentioned now in TareasObj, but i still cant display them in the view >.<

Comment: The currentObj doesn't have the keys 'TareasObj' or 'detalleProyecto'. Its not an array so I think it should be fine. It will just add new key-value pairs.